# Bypass ADAL.js login page in AngularJs SPA when site is rendered in a WebView

Tags: angularjs, webview, single-page-application, adal, adal.js

How do i bypass adal.js auth of an AngularJS SPA website when the site is rendered in a WebView of a client app (Android, iOS and Windows)?
The client app is already secured using ADAL.net. Currently the user has to login twice - once on the client app and once on the website (Webview). 
Will moving to a ASP.net MVC + AngularJS architecture solve the problem or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

The authentication techniques you use for a web app rendered in a web site are completely different from the ones you use on a native application. There is no way of translating the tokens obtained by a native client in cookies to be used with a web application.
The general approach for creating a native client in the scenario you described is to have the native client directly call the web API of your SPA backend, as opposed to rendering the web site in a web view.